# Favicon is not dispaying on web page

Tags: asp.net, html, favicon

I am not able to display a favicon on the webpage. I am using IE8. I have used the below markup in a `.aspx` page:

```
<head runat="server">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" />
</head>
```

I have kept the `favicon.ico` file in the `Images`.

It is displaying on other browsers like Firefox and Chrome, but I want it to be displayed on IE. What would be the settings to do in IE?

Comment: Image displaying before Title of webpage

Comment: the word for that is `favicon`... title image sounds like the title property of the `img` tag

Comment: Is it not just a cache problem? try clearing IE cache or try it on a different computer

Comment: @middelpart, make your comment an answer – it’s most probably the correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant take few actions:

1. Set the link elements to `runat=server`
2. Move the favicon.ico to the root (if you can).
3. Use conditional comments to show the favicon for old IE
4. Clear your browser cache.

### Code Result:

```
<link runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link runat="server" rel="icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<![endif]-->
```

### Further:

Most browsers will pick up the favicon if you simply put it in the root folder, so that would be the best place to put it even if you also have a link tag that points to it.

Comment: Putting anything into the root folder (of a web server) is impossible to many authors, for good reasons. And whether and how `~` means anything in a URL depends on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file name must be `favicon.ico` and place it on the root folder not inside the images. It will display in IE too. Do not forget to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

try use this :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```